# Restrict the If block

Tags: java, android

I have an `if` condition in my Java code in Android and I want to enter the block it's the first time the user has run the app. But for the second time and thereafter, they ignore the conditions.

How can I restrict the `if` block in my Java code?

This is my if block condition:

```
if(AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(SplashActivity.this)
                 .readPrefs‌​(SplashActivity.this‌​, "language").isEmpty())
{
    AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(SplashActivity.this)
                  .writePrefs(S‌​plashActivity.this, "language","English");
}
```

Comment: could you please be more clear on what you are trying to do and what it actually does? you may want to add a code example

Comment: Let me just get my crystal ball.... one minute!

Comment: put your code in your question

Answer (score 3):

You need to have shared preference for your purpose. On first time store value true to shared preference and when next time user comes to the app get value from shared preference if that is true you dont need to call your code

Answer (score 2):

"Simple": you pick one of the options for **storing** data on the device.

And then, your code **reads** that data back every time the application starts.

See [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-store-data-locally-in-android-app-717190/) for an overview of options, and [there](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for the option you should pick (shared preferences).

In other words: the whole idea is that you have to enable yourself to **store** data; so that your code can later make decisions based on that data. That is all there is to this.